# ShareThis WordPress Plugin: Buttons Stacking Vertically

Tags: css, wordpress, sharethis

I have been utilizing the ShareThis WordPress Plugin for quite awhile now. A recent update has broken its arrangement, making all of the icons stack vertically on top of each other instead of all on the same line horizontally. I need to modify my code in order to have them displayed horizontally along the top and bottom of my posts like they used to.

Picture: http://cl.ly/image/1P1G3x2Q0u2W

Here is my code:

Script Tags:

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>

<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>

<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
stLight.options({"publisher":"03e4d9cd-293f-4d04- bf79-570a5f288168","doNotCopy":true,"hashAddressBar":false,"doNotHash":true});
var st_type="wordpress3.8.1";
</script>
```

HTML Tags:

```
<span st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' class='st_sharethis_hcount'></span>
<span st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' class='st_linkedin_hcount'></span>
<span st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' class='st_twitter_hcount'></span>
<span st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' class='st_plusone_hcount'></span>
<span st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' class='st_fblike_hcount'></span>
<span st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' class='st_facebook_hcount'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to show you a working demo without a fiddle to work with but he's my suggestion

wrap them in a div class="share" this way you can target all the span tags in it.

then use this css

```
.share span{
    display:inline;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
```

It should work

Actually, here is a [***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/Pu7Qf/)